# How to delete directory I can't spell?

Tags: bash, directory

I mistyped a directory name when building a project, and embarassingly, now I have a directory I cannot spell, so I can't run `rm -rf ..<innomable>`:

```bsh
> cd buil
build-fix-memleak/             buil�d-master-debug/       build-master-debug     ...              

> file "buil�d-master-debug"
buil�d-master-debug: cannot open `buil�d-master-debug' (No such file or directory)

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "bui*"
./build-fix-memleak
./build-master-debug
..

> ls | grep "^buil"
...
build-fix-memleak
build-group-move
build-master
build-master-debug
..
```

I can't even grep it

How do I remove it without deleting all other `build-*` dirs?

*EDIT:* Okey I actually followed jesse_b comment, and moved everything useful into a temporary directory, cleaned the current, and moved everything back again

Comment: what if you move `build-master-debug` temporarily and then `rm bui*-master-debug`?  Or you might be able to just `rm buil?d-master-debug`

Comment: haha yes, that worked. I moved everything valuable into a temporary directory, ran rm -rf, and moved it back. Thanks for making me think straight

Comment: Would you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Using `ls -b` or some hex-tool should give you the bytes as well.

Comment: @ibuprofen what would you do with that though? Use the `$'code'` format in a glob? Would that even work?

Comment: @terdon Mostly if one is curious to what the bytes are, secondly one can use it in printf. E.g. `mv "$(printf 'Foo\x07\x13Some\xf8Thing')" new`. (Was the thought.). But limited to how ls is implemented. `for f in ./*; do printf %s "$f" | xxd -g 1 ; done` is perhaps better for that.

Comment: @ibuprofen yep, that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: As for why `file "buil�d-master-debug"` does not work is that `�` is a generic replacement symbol for unprintable characters. If one copy it one do not actually copy the *real bytes* - like one sometimes can in some applications.

Answer (score 4):

You could (probably) match it with a glob such as `buil?*d-master-debug`, where the `?` matches a single character and the `*` matches *zero or more* characters. The `?` requires a match and so prevents a match to the correct `build-master-debug` directory.

```
ls -d buil?*d-master-debug     # Check for a single match
rm -rf buil?*d-master-debug    # Remove that single match
```

Comment: I haven't tried using globs with ls, but using these with `find` didn't work

Comment: @dgan because `find` is a different beast. If you do something like `find . -name 'buil?*d-master-debug' -delete` it should work (note the quotes around the glob, they're essential).

Comment: @dgan your `ls | grep "^buil"` would more idiomatically be written `ls -d buil*` (the `-d` flag prevents `ls` listing the contents of matching directories rather than the names of them)